# Can see App Clips banner only when app is installed

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, smartbanner, apple-appclips, associated-domains

I can see App Clips banner only when app is installed. But see nothing when isn't installed.

My **.well-known/apple-app-site-association** file:

```
"applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
           {
             "appID":  "ABCDEFG.com.mywebsite.MYAPP",
             "components": [
               {
                  "/": "/abc",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL"
               }
               ]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "ABCDEFG.com.mywebsite.MYAPP" ]
   },
    "appclips": {
        "apps": ["ABCDEFG.com.mywebsite.MYAPP.Clip"]
    }
}
```

Associated Domains in the app target and App Clips target are the same: webcredentials, applinks and appclips with my domain: [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoqWv.png)

On the App Store Connect domain Validated and Advanced App Clip Experiences is created.

Banner on the website:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1234567890, app-clip-bundle-id=com.mywebsite.MYAPP.Clip">
```

But I see App Clips banner only when app is installed. However empty (no any banner) is I delete an app.

Where can be a problem?

Comment: Can you please mention if the version with the App Clip is already published in the App Store?

Comment: @LiazKamper yes, of course, right with my app [Screenshot 1](https://images2.imagebam.com/8f/63/7e/a976d21356874014.png), [Screenshot 2](https://images2.imagebam.com/ea/38/25/33a0641356874016.png)

Comment: Alex, the screenshots show that you configured the App Clip experience and AASA fie correctly. But is this version with App Clip 'Ready For Sale' in the App Store?

Comment: @LiazKamper yes, sure. That's why I don't understand why I can see App Clips banner on my website only if app is installed :(

Comment: I noticed your apple-app-site-association file is missing the "{" at the start to make it proper JSON.